# VBA: Iterate a lookup function through Sheet A and append looked up values in Sheet B

Tags: excel, vba

complete VBA newbie here who is currently reading through the official Microsoft VBA/Macro tutorial.

**EDIT**
I have the following situation with 2 worksheets.

- Sheet 1 stores certain rulesets marked by "ID" that are applicable to certain data "fields"
- Sheet 2 stores a mapping logic for each "field" that is assigned to a "source system"
- Between "field" and "ID" (requirement) is a n:m relationship

Problem:

- For each "field" in table 2 look up the "ID" value in table 1 for all matching "fields" that are in table 1
- Constraint: all "fields" of a particular "source system" should have the same "IDs" assigned to them. Any rule aka "ID" that is applicable to a field is also applicable to the corresponding source system.
  Thus, the set of IDs assigned to a particular source system should be the largest set of all unique matched "IDs" across all recorded rows (aka "fields") of the source system. --> Illustrated in 4th table

Hope that helps in framing the problem.

Say sheet 1 looks like this and is the lookup table.

| ID | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_1 | a100 | a200 | z012 |
| A_2 | a200 | a300 | a400 |
| A_3 | a100 | z400 |  |

Say sheet 2 is the sheet where the value should be matched and pasted that is found in sheet 1. However, the ID field should be the total of all IDs found in sheet 1 for every unique source system in sheet 2. If there is more than ID (lookup match), then the value should not be overwritten but rather be appended by the second, third value etc.

| ID | Source system | Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | DB1 | a100 |
|  | DB1 | a200 |
|  | DB1 | a300 |
|  | DB2 | z012 |

After running the macro the table in sheet 2 should then look like:

| ID | Source system | Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_1, A_3 | DB1 | a100 |
| A_1, A_2 | DB1 | a200 |
| A_2 | DB1 | a300 |
| A_1 | DB2 | z012 |

The final version would then check the equivalence constraint of ID requirements for each source system in table 2 and **add A_1 for DB1** in row 3 to have the ID requirements for source system DB1 match across all fields.

| ID | Source system | Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_1, A_3 | DB1 | a100 |
| A_1, A_2 | DB1 | a200 |
| **A_1**, A_2 | DB1 | a300 |
| A_1 | DB2 | z012 |

I really can't think of a fitting logic that would give me the desired output. Sheet 2 is rather long btw (~20k lines)

Thank you very much in advance! Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, you should show us what you tried by your own, even if it does not return what you need. We will maybe better understand what you try accomplishing. I cannot understand which to be the matching key between the two sheets... Can you try clarifying this aspect?

Comment: Still alive? Based on what matching to make the third table using the first two ones?

Comment: Yeah, was just finishing some other work. Essentially I want to look up the fields from table A and match them in the table B column C (Field) with the result vector being the ID column in table A

Comment: but if there are more than one ID for a particular field, the looked up value should not be overwritten but rather appended.  I am thinking maybe I need a 2 step process, where I first just append the newly looked up ID values in table B and then subsequently determine the total of all IDs that correspond to a each source system in table A. I'll adjust the question to reflect that.

Comment: No need to a second step, I think. If I would conclude in the following way, based on the your last comments, will it be a correct understanding? **Processing of the two tables means comparing of all items in the three 'Feld 1-3` columns of the first sheet with items in column `Field` of the second one. If a match (for any) is found, the corresponding IDs should be returned in A:A column, comma separated**. But this does not explain at all the use of "Source system" field. Since it cannot be compared with anything form the first sheet, based on what to return "A-100" in the 4th row?

Comment: well that is what I wanted to convey but couldn't. You made it sound so easy!

Comment: The use of the column "Source system" is basically only a constraint to add an additional complexity layer in the macro programming. The final matched and recorded "ID" values in table B must be equal across all entries of a respective source system. I marked it in the question to clarify. Hope that helps

Comment: I am afraid you missed the last part... If the bolded part will be the correct algorithm, the 4th row will never appear. So, you must explain based on what to process the two sheets in a way to make it appearing. You must have something in your head when placed it there. Since we are not the mind readers, it would be good to explain what is it about, from the point of view in discussion... Edited: I could not see your last comment. I will look to the edited question to see if it produces some more light...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245445/discussion-between-aimbotter21-and-faneduru).

Comment: I am afraid I will stop here. I cannot understand what you try accomplishing and no time to understand something not understandable, sorry...

Comment: I'm curious, after running the macro, why the ID is A_1, A_2 for DB1 field a100 in Sheet2 ? From looking the table in Sheet1, I see a100 is in the field-1 first row (ID A_1) and third row (ID A_3).... so I thought the ID for DB1 field a100 in sheet2 should be A_1, A_3. Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma You are completely right! Updated the question. However, I did solve the question so far by writing a macro for a specialized lookup function that gives me all matches instead of just the first one if any. However the second part of the question, being able to assign the largest set of IDs across all individual fields coming from one source system to all those entries is still bugging me. Cheers

Comment: In sheet2, assumed after the first sub run, **the ID of** DB1 a100 : A1, A2, A3 .... DB1 a200 : A1, A3.... DB1 a300 : A2, A3 .... What to add the ID of DB1 a300 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the question partially by writing a function that basically works like a lookup function but provides all the matched results stored in a vector. This vector is then used to write the matches in the corresponding target table. The function is then looped through all lines row-wise within the target table.

See pseudocode below

```
Function AllMatchesLookup(search term, search array, results vector)
  For Each cell in search array
    If cell = search term
      current line = cell.Row
      AllMatchesLookup = AllMatchesLookup & Sheet.range(column & 
                          current line).Value 
    End If
  Next cell
End Function
```

Here's the subroutine

```
Sub 
  For current row = 1 To last row
    If search term = lookup.Value
      target cell.Value = AllMatchesLookup(search term, search 
                          array, results vector)
    End If
  Next current row
End Sub
```

The initial constraint being all requirements/IDs must match across all fields recorded for a respective system is thereby waived.